# Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined with Expected Conditions

Tags: protractor

My script failed at the expected conditions at this line:

```
let condition = EC.presenceOf (title_css);
```

The error message:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined

I tried an equivalent script in selenium Java and it works. But I am wonder why this fails in Protractor. I am new to Protractor and wonder if `ExpectedConditions` do not work for non angular.

```js
var title_css = "h1[ng-bind='::$ctrl.primaryText']"

describe ("Protractor test demo", function(){

    it ("testing site", function (){

        browser.get('https://www.eat24.com/')

        let EC = ExpectedConditions;
        var title_css = by.css (title_css);
        let condition = EC.presenceOf (title_css);
        browser.wait(condition, 30000)
    })
})
```

`ExpectedConditions` in Protractor should accept css like in Selenium / Java?

Answer (score 1):

change the EC to `EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;`

then the presenceOf part `browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element));`

Also this condition will return a promise that needs resolving

Comment: Thanks! This is what i miss out

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to read protractor API documentation first. you'll see protractor has different syntax

A few problems I noticed in your code

```
let title_css = "h1[ng-bind='::$ctrl.primaryText']" // I assume you verified it works

describe("Protractor test demo", function() {

  it("testing site", function () {

    browser.get('https://www.eat24.com/')

    let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions; // ExpectedConditions may be available as a global variable, may not, so to be safe do it this way...
    let title_element = element(by.css(title_css)); // syntax is element(by.strategy(locator))
    let condition = EC.presenceOf(title_element);
    browser.wait(condition, 30000)
  })
})
```

If you solve your problem, your next problem will be Promises, I can guarantee you that. So read how to handle them